# I want to resolve this error: "config validation failed: invalid secrets: 2 errors:"

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, polygon, chainlink

Hi I am installing a chainlink node locally.
I'm looking at the source and installing it, but I'm getting the following error and I'm stumped, I can't google it and I can't watch the video, what should I do?

Link to the video you referenced :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tIgRvc8WxQ

Here's the link to the github documentation I referenced
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install

**Error encountered :
config validation failed: invalid secrets: 2 errors:
- Database.URL: empty: must be provided and non-empty
- Password.Keystore: empty: must be provided and non-empty**

What I did :
Modify the config at the bottom config and "chainlink node start"

```
configROOT=/${HOME}/.chainlink-goerli
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=5
CHAINLINK_DEV=truechainlink_tls_port=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=wss://${ETH_URL}/
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://{SECRET_HOST}:${SECRET_PORT}/TEST?sslmode=disable
```

I installed a chainlink node and used the
I want to install the source before docker and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors...
Answer for 1st error:

```
Database.URL: empty: must be provided and non-empty :
```

Hi I guess You have to add `Database UrL` For the first error as it says in the URL
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/v1.13.0/docs/SECRETS.md
If link goes dead check this example:

```
[Database]
URL = "postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable" # Example
BackupURL = "postgresql://user:pass@read-replica.example.com:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable" # Example
AllowSimplePasswords = false # Default
```

Answer for the second error:

Add a password for `Password.Keystore: empty: must be provided and non-empty`

Go to https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/v1.13.0/docs/SECRETS.md

Check their example... to run chainlink node they have added the

```
Keystore
Keystore = "keystore_pass" # Example
```

Go to this website https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/resources/connecting-to-a-remote-database
They say you need to add an `environment variable`

https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/configuration/ In this link they gave you a list of environment variables you can add and the thing you have to add is `Database_URL` as given after scrolling down